# SQL Insert Query For Multiple Max IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, insert-update, insert-into

Table w:

```
|ID|Comment|SeqID|
|1 |bajg   | 1   |
|1 |2423   | 2   |
|2 |ref    | 1   |
|2 |comment| 2   |
|2 |juk    | 3   |
|3 |efef   | 1   |
|4 | hy    | 1   |
|4 | 6u    | 2   |
```

How do I insert a standard new comment for each ID for a new SeqID (SeqID increase by 1)

The Below query results in the highest SeqID:

```
Select *
From w
Where SEQID = 
(select max(seqid)
from w)
```

Table w:

```
|2 |juk    | 3   |
```

Expected Result
Table w:

```
|ID|Comment|SeqID|
|1 |sqc    | 3   |
|2 |sqc    | 4   |
|3 |sqc    | 2   |
|4 |sqc    | 3   |
```

Will I have to go through and insert all the values (new comment as sqc) I want into the table using the below, or is there a faster way?

```
INSERT INTO table_name
 VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: where does the sqc come from?  I'm a little unclear on what you're trying to actually accomplish?  Updating an existing record, or generating a new record?

Comment: sqc is a new comment I want to add. The table is all comments and each new comment added is added in sequence. For example: if I add a new comment "hihi" for ID 1 (looking at data in table w), it will add a new row in the database |1 |hihi|3| . So generating a new record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (ID, Comment, SeqID)
SELECT ID, 'sqc', MAX(SeqID) + 1
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68a6b/1)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off just calculating the value when you query.  Define an `identity` column on the table, say `CommentId` and run a query like:

```
select id, comment,
       row_number() over (partition by comment order by CommentId) as SeqId
from t;
```

What is nice about this approach is that the ids are always sequential, you don't have no opportunities for duplicates, the table does not have to be locked to when inserting, and the sequential ids work even for updates and deletes.